# Nsubstitute - Raise event of mocked object when handler uses generics

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

We mock an interface which has an event on it like so:

```
public interface IThing<TKey, TValue>
{
    event EventHandler<Message<TKey, TValue>> OnMessage;
}
```

Using NSubstitue we make a mock of the interface and try to raise the event using NSubstitute guidelines:

```
var mockThing = Substitute.For<IThing>();

mockThing.OnMessage += Raise.EventWith(???)
```

Despite many attempts, we can't get that line to compile - is it just a case of placing the generic types and arguments in the correct position?

The actual OnMessage() function called will look like this:

```
private void OnMessage(object sender, Message<string, string> message)
```

Comment: This seems to be a dublicate of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930227/how-to-raise-an-event-with-nsubstitute-with-eventhandlert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like

```
mockThing.OnMessage += Raise.Event<EventHandler<Message<string, string>>>(this, new Message<string, string>("yes", "what"))
```